# Multiple objects listening for the same key

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form. Using JavaScript, I want to:

1. Enable line breaks on <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Disable the default event for <kbd>Enter</kbd> no matter where you click(meaning I want to prevent the script from sending my file when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Generally I know how to do this. Below is my JavaScript code for each part. I tested them and they work perfectly fine on their own. (Note: there are several `textbox` and `input` elements which I have saved in a variable.)

```
textbox.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        for(i=0; i<textbox.length; i++) {
            textbox[i].value = textbox[i].value + "\n";
            return false;
        };

    }
});


input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key=13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I also tried deleting

```
event.preventDefault();
```

from my function for textbox and instead using

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

    }
});
```

But obviously that didn't work either. On other questions I read that that you can't have multiple objects for the same key, but I'm not sure if that's the case here?

Another thing I tried was to delete the function for input and calling a function when the body is loaded, which looked like this:

```
function disableEnter(e) {
    var key = e.which;

    if(key == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

However, once again it did not work.

Is it simply not possible to connect two functions to one key? If so, is there any way I could get around this and still prevent the default for the *whole* page?

**EDIT:** I just realized that it may not be entirely clear: I have several `textarea` and `input` elements in my form, which I saved in arrays called `textbox` and `input` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easy way to do that.  I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but this is an example with a simple form using `input` and `textarea`:

```js
// set up the node lists
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var textbox = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

// loop through the input elements & add the listener to each
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  addListener(input[i]);
}

// loop through the textarea elements & add the listener to each
for (var j = 0; j < textbox.length; j++) {
  addListener(textbox[j]);
}

// function to assign the listener
function addListener(el) {
  el.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {  // if ENTER was pressed
      event.preventDefault();
      if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == "TEXTAREA") {  // if a textarea
        e.target.value = e.target.value + "\n";
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="Input 1"><br /><br />
  <input placeholder="Input 2"><br /><br />
  <textarea placeholder="Textbox 1" rows=5></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you very much, that worked perfectly, I just had to wrap the for loops in a function that gets called whenever the window is loaded"